# GAE Python 2.7, no _io module?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webob

I can't import WebOb 1.1 with the Python 2.7 runtime, as WebOb imports io, io imports _io, which is blocked by the SDK. Is there a way to whitelist _io? It is obviously not supposed to be blacklisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context, it sounds like you're trying to run your app on the `dev_appserver`. The dev_appserver does not yet support the Python 2.7 runtime; for now you'll have to do your development and testing on appspot.